# Build array of indexes of set in java

Tags: java, arrays, set

I have a Set of integers and I want to create an array which contains the index of each element in the source place, like this:

```
Set<Integer> source = {2,4,5};
```

**required result:**

```
Integer[] result = [null, null, 0, null, 1, 2]
```

I tried this code but got an error: "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final":

```
private Integer[] getIndexArray(Set<Integer> sourceSet) {
        final Integer[] resultArray = new Integer[Constants.MAX_IDS];
        Integer index = 0;
        sourceSet.forEach(id -> resultArray[id] = index++);
        return resultArray;
    }
```

Comment: and what if your source is { 2, 4, 345532342234 } ? this is beyond max integer value and will waste a lot of memory with null values in an array. a much better solution would be a Map<Integer, Integer> where you map each value to its position.

Comment: make "index" final in your code. the compiler is afraid you will try to move it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better and nicer solution:

```
static int[] getIndexArray(Set<Integer> sourceSet) {
        final int[] resultArray = new int[sourceSet.max().get() + 1];
        sourceSet.zipWithIndex().forEach(t -> resultArray[t._1] = t._2);
        return resultArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Logic:

In main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> source = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5));
        int max = Collections.max(source);
        Integer[] result = new Integer[max + 1];

        int index = 0;
        for (Integer element : source) {
            result[element] = index++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Output:

```
[null, null, 0, null, 1, 2]
```